# why is my main.js not loading?

Tags: ajax, wp-enqueue-script

I am about to start coding my Ajax Post Script and I tried testing to see if the main.js is loading and it is not:

```
alert('Linked');
```

I looked through my scripts file, but I cannot make out what could be the matter newsletter-subscriber-scripts.php:

```
<?php

  // Add Scripts
  function ns_add_scripts(){
    wp_enqueque_style('ns-main-style',plugins_url().'/newsletter-subscriber/css/style.css');
    wp_enqueque_script('ns-main-script',plugins_url().'/newsletter-subscriber/js/main.js');
  }

add_action('wp_enqueque_scripts', 'ns_add_scripts');

 ?>
```

I tried changing wp_enquewue_scripts() inside the ns_add_scripts() function, but that wasn't it. I cleared cache, but that wasn't it.

Here is my file structure:

[image]

My newsletter-subscriber.php file:

```
<?php

  /**
  * Plugin Name: Newsletter Subscriber
  * Description: A form to subscribe to a newsletter
  * Version 1.0
  * Author: Daniel Cortes
  *
  **/

  // Exit if Accessed Directly
  if(!defined('ABSPATH')){
    exit;
  }

  // Loading Scripts
  require_once(plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) . '/includes/newsletter-subscriber-scripts.php');

  // Loading Class
  require_once(plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) . '/includes/newsletter-subscriber-class.php');

  function register_newsletter_subscriber(){
    register_widget('Newsletter_Subscriber_Widget');
  }

  add_action('widgets_init','register_newsletter_subscriber');

 ?>
```

Comment: You've spelled enqueue incorrectly.

Comment: @Milo, of course :( any pointers on how to stare at code without missing the obvious? Anyway, go ahead and place your answer as the correct one.